# ¿Cómo implementar la segunda forma del ejemplo sin gridview?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net

Estoy creando una web tipo Rentcar. La verdad no quiero que cuando realice la consulta a la base de datos,no quiero usar Gridview ya que este implementa los resultados en forma de tabla,osea todos los datos en una fila horizontal.

Miren este diseño que hice,no quiero lo primero,sino lo segundo.¿Cómo implemento lo segundo?Todo los estoy haciendo en C# asp.net con SQL Server,todo web.

Tienen alguna idea de como hacerlo?

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Foto        Nombre      Apellido      Dirección       Teléfono
------------------------------------------------------------------------
          Luis        Batista       Las Palmas     888-888-8888
------------------------------------------------------------------------
          Maria       Perez         Villa nueva    777-777-7777
------------------------------------------------------------------------



________________________________________________________________________
 __________
|           |Luis Batista
|         |Las palmas
|           |
|___________|888-888-8888                      Aquí link  Buscar detalles*
_________________________________________________________________________
```

Con este código lleno un DropDownList con nombres de Marcas de autos:

```
private void dropdownMarca()
{
    DropDownListMarcas.DataSource = Consultar("SELECT * FROM Marca");
    DropDownListMarcas.DataTextField = "Marca";
    DropDownListMarcas.DataValueField = "Id";
    DropDownListMarcas.DataBind();
    DropDownListMarcas.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Seleccione una marca", "0"));
}
```

Tengo este codigo en el boton buscar:

```
protected void btnbuscar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = MEGATRON; Initial Catalog = RentCar; Integrated Security = True");
    try
    {

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Autos WHERE Marca like '" + DropDownListMarcas.SelectedItem.Text + "%'", conn);


        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        this.GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Todo este código me está llenando un Gridview,pero no quiero un Gridview,sino la segunda forma como mencioné arriba en el ejemplo.

Comment: La respuesta puede ser muy larga. Creo que la forma más límpia es hacerlo con un gridview, aunque deberás crear una plantilla (Template) para tu formato. Puedes ver algún ejemplo en [este enlace](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/web-forms/overview/data-access/custom-formatting/using-templatefields-in-the-gridview-control-cs).

Comment: @RogerTorné Amigo,el gridview es muy simplón(si se puede decir de esa forma).¿Has visto alguna web de rentas de autos con resultados parecidos a los que planteo aquí? Algún ejemplo de como hacerlo?

Comment: Si no deseas usar GridView, puedes crear un UserControl con el diseño que muestras usando PictureBox, Label, que tenga las propiedades públicas que deseas asignar y así asignar los valores correspondientes a cada objeto cuando sea necesario.

Comment: @J.Rodríguez Ya hice lo que buscaba.